# D3.js : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, initialization, undefined

I'm having a really weird problem with d3.js initilization. In the d3.js script,  at the very beginning, it tries to get `var d3_document = this.document;` but it pops the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

when debugging, `this.document` returns undefined.

I'm using `yo webapp` to generate the project. It uses bower as package manager and gulp for the build process (that uses babel for the ES2015 features).

The funny thing is that I've tested it with xampp and it works fine!

I would appreciate some advice!Thnx!

Comment: Good detail about the setup. Without that detail, I couldn't have answered the question.

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like something (Babel, most likely) is inserting `"use strict";` at the beginning of the D3 script file or combining it into another file with "use strict" at the top. That means `this` at global scope (or in a function called without a specific `this`) is no longer a reference to the global object, it's `undefined`. (Whereas in "loose" mode or in a function called with no specific `this` value, `this` at global scope is a reference to the global object, which is also accessible via the global variable `window1.)

You need to remove your `d3.js` from the list of scripts being transformed by Babel and just include it as-is. Assuming you're using the normal `d3.js` file, it looks like this:

```
!function() {
  var d3 = {
    version: "3.5.16"
  };
  var d3_arraySlice = [].slice, d3_array = function(list) {
    return d3_arraySlice.call(list);
  };
  var d3_document = this.document;
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...lots of stuff here...
  // ...
  // ...
}();
```

That relies on being run in loose mode.

Comment: Thnx, definitely it's babel that appends `'use restrict'` to the scripts. For anyone having this same issue, go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821312/how-to-remove-global-use-strict-added-by-babel) to know how to resolve it in babel 5 and babel 6.