# In Angular app, how do I import d3 and use d3.js scripts?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I'm using d3.js version 3 script in my angular app.

I have installed d3 in angular app using command

```
npm i d3@3
```

And imported d3 as

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Even though I imported d3 as above,
 I'm getting error

```
Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Users/srikar.vodeti/Downloads/imp/dashboardVisual/networkDiagram/node_modules/@types/d3/index")'. 106 var tree = d3.layout.tree()
```

when i use d3. any method

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what error you are getting ? can you add that also in your question?

Comment: yes mentioned the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install d3 and type declaration

```
npm install d3 --save
npm install --save @types/d3
```

then import d3

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Please let me know if it is not working.

Comment: No, it's not working..
Getting error ```Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Users/srikar.vodeti/Downloads/imp/dashboardVisual/networkDiagram/node_modules/@types/d3/index")'.

106 var tree = d3.layout.tree()``` when i use d3.layout.tree();

Comment: please create stackblitz demo. so i can have better look on it

Comment: here is  a d3 working sample , you can refer this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-svr-sample

Comment: you can use var tree = (d3 as any).layout.tree(). then vs code will not show error

Comment: After doing the above steps.. got below error and able to solve finally...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400413/d3-js-runtime-error-after-upgrade-to-angular-8