# webpack `this` not pointing to window (Chart.js breaks)

Tags: javascript, webpack, chart.js

I've just started playing around with Webpack and migrating one older application from a set of grunt tasks to using webpack. It's looking very fine so far, however I can't figure out how to get chart.js working in that context.

Chart.js is trying to register a global variable `Chart` like this:

```
(function(){

"use strict";

//Declare root variable - window in the browser, global on the server
var root = this,
    previous = root.Chart;

//Occupy the global variable of Chart, and create a simple base class
var Chart = function(context){
    // some stuff
}

root.Chart = Chart;
```

This does actually break, because when run in webpack, `this` is `undefined`, rather than window or global.

The error it raises is in the line

```
root.Chart = Chart;
```

and says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined
```

Is there any chance, I can get Chart.js to run without patching it's source code? Actually it uses the `this` trick all over the place, and I want to be able to update chart.js in the future.

Comment: We cannot see how this function is being invoked, but it's very bizarre that it would start with `"use strict";` and then assume that `this` is `window` on the *very next line*. One of very very well documented effects of using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is that `this` no longer defaults to `window`. Is the function by chance being invoked using `}).call(window)` at the end?

Comment: I assume this is because the bundler wraps every module in something like this. Are you using the Babel loader?

Comment: It's vanilla chart.js - as to be found here: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/d2b73bdc5b5fd9b714dcab4c542eec750babd8bc/Chart.js 
It errors as the JS interpreter runs through webpacks generated JS file

Comment: yes, using babel loader

Comment: Then you'll need to make sure the `strict-mode` plugin isn't being used in Babel. [See this question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821312/how-to-remove-global-use-strict-added-by-babel)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now trying to figure out how to tell the babel loader to use a blacklist. The hard part in webpack is definitely the documentation...

Comment: It's a bug in the library - just fix it by changing the very last line from `.call(this)` to `.call(window || global)` and send them a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [imports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/) to adjust dependency context like this:

Install the loader with `npm install imports-loader`

and add it to loaders in your webpack configuration:

```
{
    test: require.resolve('chart.js'),
    use: 'imports-loader?this=>window'
}
```