# How to get webpack2 and underscore-template loader + babel to work without getting "Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'with' in strict mode (5:0)"

Tags: webpack-2, underscore.js-templating, babel-6

I have a underscore template loader in my webpack2 config that is transpiled with babel. It fails at compile time because `with` is used in the code compiled code. Here is the relevant part in my loaders in `webpack.config.js`:

I have this section under loaders:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: [
                    ['es2015', { modules: false }],
                    'es2016',
                    'es2017',
                    'stage-3',
                ],
            },
        },
        {
            loader: 'ejs-loader',
        },
    ],
};
```

This is what I want and I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/table/row.html
Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'with' in strict mode (5:0)

  3 | var __t, __p = '', __e = _.escape, __j = Array.prototype.join;
  4 | function print() { __p += __j.call(arguments, '') }
> 5 | with (obj) {
    | ^
  6 | 
  7 |  _.each(tableKeys, (k) => { ;
  8 | __p += '\n  <td>' +
```

If I remove the `babel` part completely it works but with ES6 code not transpiled:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'ejs-loader',
        },
    ],
};
```

I have also seen [this question about removing strict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33821820/351705) and have tried several things related to es2015 applying strict. I think I have tried *every* solution in that question including hotpatching workaround and I still get the same error. In the end i tried this:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: [
                ],
            },
        },
        {
            loader: 'ejs-loader',
        },
    ],
};
```

I though this should do the same as without the bable pass, but I get the same error here. Somehow without any presets I get the same error.

**EDIT**

I have also tried to work around it by passing `variable` in `query` and I have made that work with `ejs-loader`, however I'm not looking for a solution where all the templates need changing.

I have made a [repository which illustrates](https://github.com/westerp/underscore-babel/tree/transpile) the problem. The master branch has babel-loader commented out and works with `with` while the `transpile` branch will have compile errors even though `{ modules: false }` is passed and I have a branch called `transpile-no-presets` where all presets in package.json is removed and the error is still showing.

Comment: I'm running into this problem too. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

By default Underscore `.template` put your data in the scope using a `with` statement. See [Underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

I think the cleanest solution is to instruct your `ejs-loader` to not compile to `with` statements but to use a [temporary variable](https://github.com/okonet/ejs-loader#options) instead:

```
{
    loader: 'ejs-loader?variable=data',
},
```

...and change your templates to reference the temporary variable.

From:

```
<ul>
  <% _.each(test, (n) => { %>
    <li>This is line number <%- n %></li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

to:

```
<ul>
  <% _.each(data.test, (n) => { %>
    <li>This is line number <%- n %></li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Comment: In this question I'm looking for a solution without changing the templates. i.e. with `with` in the code and without it blowing up compile time. (I actually have a working test in the branch `use-variable` but it will be last resort as rewriting the templates is time consuming and introduce bugs)

Comment: So you want to keep the `with` statements into the compiled bundle?

Comment: Yes. It was compiled with `with` originally and when I comment out the `babel-loader` step in `use` it works. According to the question I linked its supposed to be easy to not require strict but none of the solutions seem to work so I'm beginning to suspect that changes in webpack2 might be to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Use version 1.0 of [`underscore-template-loader`](https://npmjs.com/package/underscore-template-loader) instead.