# babel 7 - how to prevent adding of "strict mode"

Tags: babeljs

I looked at many posts but still cannot get this to work :(

I have .babelrc

```
{
  "comments": false,
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["ios 7"]
      }
    }],
    ["minify"]
  ]
}
```

I want to tell babel to **not** add `"use strict"` (anywhere)

How is this done ?

Comment: Is the issue that Babel adds `use strict` to your CommonJS modules? Not adding `use strict` to an ES module (with `import` and `export`) would be a violation of the spec.

Comment: I don't use commonjs or modules

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Babel assumes by default that files being transformed are ES modules. Since that is not the case for you, you'll want to tell it that. You can check out [the docs for the `"sourceType"` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype), but essentially you want to add:

```
"sourceType": "script"
```

in your Babel options.

Comment: Ty for the explanation. It works properly for me.

Comment: This helped me regarding babel throwing errors when it came across code that wasn't strict-mode compliant. However, now it's adding "use strict" to the top of all my files. Any idea how to stop that?

Comment: @yts Consider `'unambiguous'` instead of `'script'`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work for me either. Might have to do with the version of gulp-babel I'm using. I'll have to get back to working on it at a later time.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Looks like changing the sourceType allowed babel (6) to read in my non strict compliant code, but I had to also add `modules: false` to the "env" presets options to prevent it from appending "use strict" to the top of the files. Basically like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39225403/1825352, except I'm using "env" instead of "es2015"

Comment: @yts Yup. See the duplicate flagged on this question. It also goes over using `modules: false`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth What's interesting is that `modules: false` alone did not solve this issue. Babel was still trying to read in the files in strict mode unless I also changed the `sourceType`