# How to force disable "use strict" mode generated by Babeljs

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am trying to set up Babel compiler which converts ES6 and higher Javascript syntax to ES5. However, I faced one weird problem, when it converts to ES5 adds "use strict" in the top of the line, since the whole project is not written in strict mode it causes errors. I would like to disable this functionality. 
I have seen a couple of solutions online but none of them worked for me.
I followed these steps [link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode/) but did not work.

This is how my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "webplatform",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Web interface Platform",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel htdocs/es6 -d htdocs/js"
  },
  "author": "harry",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-strict-mode": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3"
  }
}
```

And `.babelrc` is here

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-strict-mode", {
      "strict": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

When I run the command `npm run build` it converts everything fine just "use strict" is messing me up :(

Comment: yo check all responses of this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821312/how-to-remove-global-use-strict-added-by-babel

Comment: @Olian04 I have seen that source but did not work for me.

Comment: There are tons of answers there, please try some of the more recent ones. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43024673/6224823

Comment: @Olian04 My project is written in PHP and there are more like node-based answers and the rest are the same steps I have used. But I will check them all again :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020178/can-i-disable-ecmascript-strict-mode-for-specific-functions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827968/babel-7-how-to-prevent-adding-of-strict-mode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973442/how-to-stop-babel-from-transpiling-this-to-undefined-and-inserting-use-str/34983495#34983495 should cover this.

Comment: @NathanWright Thanks a lot that worked for me. Adding `"sourceType": "script"` in `.babelrc` fixed my issue