Getting reserved keyword error in node modules
I am trying to upgrade some babel packages in my code and after upgrading these package i am getting an error like:
D:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\init-package-json\lib\default-input.js: Unexpected reserved word 'package'. (49:18)

Here are packages i upgraded :
 "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.22.0",
        "@babel/node": "^7.22.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
        "babel-loader": "^9.2.1",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
}

.babelrc :
{
    "presets": [
        "env"
    ]
}

I am getting this error while building code. Here is command to build code.
"build": "@babel/node buildScripts/build.js",

Error screenshot :

Any suggestions how to fix this issue. Any help/suggestions are appreciated.
Many Thanks.

This question is similar to: JavaScript - package is a reserved keyword. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It could be the case that Babel (used by OP) is enabling strict mode by default, hence rejecting this code by another package. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821312/how-to-remove-global-use-strict-added-by-babel

@phuzi, I havnt added this keywork it is being used in another node_js package which i cant modify

Thanks @johnnyaug, i'll check this one

I apologise. I have retracted my close vote.

The issue is that Babel 7.0 and up doesn’t recognize the env preset anymore. just switch it to @babel/preset-env in your .babelrc.

Install the new preset:
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev


Update your .babelrc:
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}



Try building again
update:
If the issue persists, try disabling strict mode: Add "sourceType": "unambiguous" to .babelrc:
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "sourceType": "unambiguous"
}


Thanks @aazizzailani, but still same issue..

Try disabling strict mode: Add "sourceType"; "unambiguous" to .babelrc @AmitK.

Tried but no luck

make sure you’re not using it as a variable name or parameter
check the build script (buildScripts/build.js) for any usage of package as a variable or identifier, or try running babel with node
npx babel-node buildScripts/build.js


No @scar17off, I am not using this variable in code. it's in node packages only.

npx @babel/node buildScripts/build.js command is working fine but when i use npm run build command getting same error

try updating your .babelrc to this:
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "sourceType": "script"
}

the issue is likely because babel is treating your code as a module by default, which enforces strict mode and makes 'package' a reserved word. setting sourceType to "script" should fix it.

tried but got some other errors like import and extend not supported @scar17off
