# Disable "use strict" in babel-standalone

Tags: babeljs

[Using Babel-Standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone), I am trying to disable `use strict` so that I may use the deprecated `with` statement per [the es2015 preset reference](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/).

```
var code = "with (p) {  // do something }";
var output = Babel.transform(code, { presets: [['es2015', {"loose": true}]] }).code;
```

this gives me this error:

```
babel.js:17955 Uncaught SyntaxError: unknown: 'with' in strict mode (1:5)
```

How do i disable strict mode using Babel Standalone?

Comment: Try to put it in a function and call it (instead of letting Bebel's strict scope to run it)

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do that?

Comment: I'm no JS programmer, however: `Function ('return 1+1')()`. `Function`'s constructor doesn't inherit strictness (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020178/can-i-disable-ecmascript-strict-mode-for-specific-functions#6039163)).

Comment: Anyway, just to make it a little less "hackish", it would be better to create another `CreateNoStrictFunction(code) { return Function(code); }` function.

Comment: Wrapping the code in a function seems to have no effect since Babel is parsing the JS,

Comment: Oh, OK sorry. However, you can pass the `strictMode` flag as an option: 
`var output = Babel.transform(code, { strictMode: false, presets: [['es2015', {"loose": true}]] }).code;` (see [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-strict-mode/))

Comment: This gives this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: [BABEL] unknown: Unknown option: base.strictMode. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134413/discussion-between-shmuel-h-and-doug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the `parserOpts` property which corresponds to [options.js](https://github.com/babel/babylon/blob/6773279039f88cdbca5bc3fc0b930c0c07a894c7/src/options.js) in [Babylon](https://github.com/babel/babylon)

```
var output = Babel.transform(code, 
{ 
   presets: ['es2015'], 
   parserOpts: { strictMode: false } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Babel parses files as ES6 modules. You'll need to tell it not to do that, with something like

```
var output = Babel.transform(code, { sourceType: 'script' });
```