# Why can't I define a global variable in a type="module"

Tags: javascript

I have a script tag
`<script type="module" src="d.js"></script>`
and In that script tag I define a global variable like this `df = 324`.
When I do this I get a reference error `Uncaught ReferenceError: df is not defined`. Why is this?

Comment: declare it using windows keyword like windows.df = 324

Comment: Okay, that helps but is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020178/can-i-disable-ecmascript-strict-mode-for-specific-functions#:~:text=No%2C%20you%20can't%20disable%20strict%20mode%20per%20function.&text=Notice%20how%20we%20can%20define,that%20strict%20immediately%20invoked%20function.

Comment: you should code with strict mode, its better

Comment: I guess so but sometimes it's just easier to get things done quickly.

Comment: I don't get it? why turn it off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because modules are by default in strict mode

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

If you try:

```
"use strict";
df = 324;
```

It wont work either

```js
"use strict";
df = 324;
```

Without

```js
df = 324;

console.log(df);
```